# coordinatorlayout can not see framelayout frequently

Tags: android, webview, scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

this is my xml layout tree:
[image]

when i open app,and everything is well! i can scroll the page to show/hide titlebar or footerbar,but when i do something like remove all views in framelayout,and add some others view into framelayout, the framelayout just gone!

`webFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
 webFrameLayout.addView(newView);`

i had try to handle it,but i can't. i can't see the framelayout in uiautomatorviewer.

and i had make some breakpoint in coordinatorlayout.
when onlayout() method called:coordinatorlayout has 3 child.but in uiautomatorviewer tree,i just see 2 child!

framelayout is gone.any one can help me?

[image]

my xml is :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_tool"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FEFEFE"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="inno.video.downloader.videodownloader.view.FooterBehaviorDependAppBar"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_home"
            style="@style/BrowserBottomToolItem"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/v_home"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_count"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_tab_count"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_item_text_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_item_text_size"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_background"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/icon_gray"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_bookmarks"
            style="@style/BrowserBottomToolItem"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/v_bookmark_border"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_more"
            style="@style/BrowserBottomToolItem"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/v_more_vert"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_height"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <include layout="@layout/search_bar"/>


        <include layout="@layout/search_bar_page_search"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_relayout_ok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/main_relayout_ok"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16sp"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </Button>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--web layout-->
<!--this framelayout is gone when i add/remove views-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/web_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You have two AppBarLayout and three FrameLayout. Which one did you mean?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท sorry，the framelayout id is web_content.

Comment: Have you tried any other layout instead of `FrameLayout` ?

Comment: @JeelVankhede yes,i try linearlayout but not work.

Comment: Can you post code where `FrameLayout` not found?

Comment: @JeelVankhede when i call `webFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
            webFrameLayout.addView(newView);`

Comment: what's `newView` in here `webFrameLayout.addView(newView);`? are you adding dynamic view to that `FrameLayout`? if yes, then don't forget to add `LayoutParams` for that `childview`.